# wx button click only displaying dialog for one when either is clicked

Tags: python, button, user-interface, wxpython

Ok, so I am playing around and trying to get an understanding of how to make GUI's with buttons, I figured i would start simple and make one with two buttons that displays a different message depending on which one is clicked. I made the first button and tested it... worked fine, made the second button and when i tested it i get the message for the second button when i click the first button, and nothing when i click the second button. I tried searching around but it doesn't seem anyone else had this issue so I am obviously doing something wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):

    def OnOpen(self,e):
        self.dirname=''
        dlg=wx.FileDialog(self,'Choose a File',self.dirname,'','*.*',wx.OPEN)

        if dlg.ShowModal()==wx.OK:
            self.filename=dlg.GetFileName()
            self.dirname=dlg.GetDirectory()
            f=open(os.path.join(self.dirname,self.filename),'r')
            self.Control.SetValue(f.read())
            f.close()
            dlg.Destroy()

    def OnAbout(self,e):
        dlg=wx.MessageDialog(self,'Aoxx','Author',wx.OK)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()

    def OnExit(self,e):
        dlg=wx.MessageDialog(self,'Exit','Terminate',wx.OK)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        self.Close(True)
        dlg.Destroy()

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Frame works',size=(450,600))
        panel=wx.Panel(self)

        self.CreateStatusBar()

        filemenu=wx.Menu()
        self.filemenu=wx.Menu()
        menubar=wx.MenuBar()
        menubar.Append(filemenu,'&File')
        #menubar.Append(filemenu,'&Help')
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

        MenuOpen=filemenu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN,'&Open','File Dir')
        MenuExit=filemenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY,'E&xit','Term')
        MenuAbout=filemenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT,'&About','Info')

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU,self.OnOpen,MenuOpen)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU,self.OnExit,MenuExit)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU,self.OnAbout,MenuAbout)



        pic1=wx.Image('C:\Users\******\Pictures\Tri.bmp', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP).ConvertToBitmap()
        self.button=wx.BitmapButton(panel,-1, pic1,pos=(10,10))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.ClickTri,self.button)
        self.button.SetDefault()

        pic2=wx.Image('C:\Users\******\Pictures\ClickWin.bmp', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP).ConvertToBitmap()
        self.buton=wx.BitmapButton(panel,-1,pic2,pos=(220,10))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.ClickWin,self.button)


    def ClickTri(self,event):
        dlg=wx.MessageDialog(self,'No touching the TriForce Rook!','HEY!!!',wx.OK)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()       

    def ClickWin(self,event):
        dlg=wx.MessageDialog(self,'You would.....','REALLY?',wx.OK)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()

        self.Show(True)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame=Frame(None,id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant have 2 `self.button` make the second one `self.button2` or something

Comment: If i wanted the button to open a new frame would i need to define another class under that one? exp 
`def ClickTri(self,event):
     class Frame2(wx.Frame):
     ....`

Comment: it depends what you wanted ... you would probably need a new frame defined somewhere ... although not in your click event  you would do
`def OnClick(self,evt):f2 = SomeOtherFrame();f2.Show()`